# How to correctly escape "%" sign when using pattern rules and patsubst in GNU make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile like the following:

```
m1:
    @echo building m1

m1_:
    @echo building m1_


m2:
    @echo building m2

m2_:
    @echo building m2_

m3_DEPS = m2 m1

SUBSTITUTE=$(patsubst %,%_,$($@_DEPS))
.SECONDEXPANSION:

#%: $$(SUBSTITUTE)
%:  $$(patsubst \%,\%_,$$($$@_DEPS))
    @echo Building $@
    @echo Dependencies are $^
```

The key line is

```
%:  $$(patsubst \%,\%_,$$($$@_DEPS))
```

I am using both a pattern rule and patsubst, which itself uses percentage signs. I thought I could escape the `%` character with a `\`, but I am still not getting the expected behaviour. Running "make m3" gives the output

```
building m2
building m1
Building m3
Dependencies are m2 m1
```

However, I expect to get

```
building m2_
building m1_
Building m3
Dependencies are m2_ m1_
```

Commenting out that line and calling `patsubst` indirectly through a variable does in fact produce that output.

```
SUBSTITUTE=$(patsubst %,%_,$($@_DEPS))

%: $$(SUBSTITUTE)
```

Also, I have tested that using a non-pattern rule works, which makes me think it is something to do with the interaction of pattern rules and percentage signs:

```
m3:  $$(patsubst %,%_,$$($$@_DEPS))
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`\` in makefile context is for line continuation, not for "escaping".  To escape things you hide them in a variable:

```
PERCENT := %
```

The idea is, at the time a makefile fragment is parsed where the escaped character is meaningful, you escape it.

So, in your situation, you have to use `$$(PERCENT)`:

`$$(patsubst $$(PERCENT),$$(PERCENT)_,$$($$@_DEPS))`

Comment: This is like what I did with hiding the entire expression in a variable, but more directly answers the question.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes I did not notice you did that.  I just saw "this does not appear to be possible" and I skipped the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to hide '%' from the pattern rule, but in this case you can work around it:

```
%: $$(addsuffix _,$$($$*_DEPS))
    @echo Building $@
    @echo Dependencies are $^
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be possible.

For a few workarounds, see the question and Beta's answer.