Make: wildcard including rule name
I am producing artifacts foo.out, bar.out, and qux.out. I have a rule %.cooked: %.raw.

For all files foo-★.raw, I need foo.out to depend on foo-★.cooked
Likewise for bar and qux

Currently, I am not restricting the raw files that are being built, so make bar.out is wastefully cooking dozens of foo-1.raw, foo-2a.raw, foo-2b.raw, etc. which is really eating into my time.
I tried using secondary expansion:
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(OUTFILES): %.out: $$(patsubst %.raw,%.cooked,$$(wildcard $$%-*.raw))
    build $< --output $@

but it seems that this ended up being empty and nothing was built.

$$(patsubst %.raw,%.cooked,$$(wildcard $$*-*.raw)) doesn't do it unfortunately. I get the same behavior.

Try $(OUTFILES): %.out: $$(subst .raw,.cooked,$$(wildcard %*.raw)). $$(patsubst %.raw,%.cooked,…) doesn't work because % is replaced with the stem from %.out.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19324181/4580217 yikes, I see. Yep, that does it. I'll stick with $$(call instead, as I believe it's more readable.

@urznow Oops, you're right. But subst is somehow not very robust. foo.rawhammer.raw would become foo.cookedhammer.cooked...

@RenaudPacalet: I agree, but how else to avoid the % ?

@urznow: $(OUTFILES): %.out: $$(addsuffix .cooked,$$(basename $$(wildcard $$*-*.raw)))

@RenaudPacalet: Much better :)   And I have now spotted the link posted by OP to stackoverflow.com/a/19324181/14403369 which uses a macro as a standin for the %.

Combining Renaud's suggestion of using $$* with a layer of indirection behind $$(call has done the trick:
OUT_raws = $(patsubst %.raw,%.cooked,$(wildcard $(1)-*.raw))

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(OUTFILES): %.out: $$(call OUT_raws,$$*)
    build $< --output $@

